# How can I effectively use the "highest()" function? Or is there another way?

Tags: pine-script

How do I find the highest price over a number of days where the number of days keep changing?

Can I use the function "highest()" with a variable inside the parenthases that holds the new number each time it is passed to it? When I do this it bombs.

Comment: What is the error message? And if you are getting an error, how are you able to see if `prevdaysinmn` has a value? It should not work on your chart. Please share your full code.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question to how I should have asked it. But the way I find if a section of code is working, is to comment out other sections of code and run it.